# wordcount.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `htab_init'

Tags: c, reference, makefile

Hi I have problem with my makefile and a just dont know what is wrong i tried multiple possibilities and it didnt work, what should i do ?

stdout terminal:

gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -o wordcount -static io.o wordcount.o libhtable.a
wordcount.o: In function `main':
wordcount.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to`htab_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wordcount] Error 1

```
 CFLAGS=-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
 CPPFLAGS=-std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall
 PROGS=wordcount wordcount-dynamic
 LIBFILES=htab_clear.o htab_init.o htab_lookup_add.o htab_free.o htab_foreach.o htab_remove.o hash_function.o

 all: $(PROGS)


wordcount.o: wordcount.c htable.h
    gcc $(FLAGS) -c wordcount.c -o wordcount.o

io.o:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c io.c -o io.o

hash_function.o: hash_function.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c hash_function.c

htab_clear.o: htab_clear.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htab_clear.c -o htab_clear.o

htab_init.o: htab_init.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htab_init.c -o htab_init.o

htab_lookup_add.o: htab_lookup_add.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htab_lookup_add.c -o htab_lookup_add.o

htab_free.o: htab_free.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htab_free.c -o htab_free.o

htab_foreach.o: htab_foreach.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htable_foreach.c -o htable_foreach.o

htab_remove.o: htab_remove.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c htab_remove.c -o htab_remove.o



libhtable.a: $(LIBFILES)
    ar crs libhtable.a $(LIBFILES)


libhtable.so: $(LIBFILES)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o libhtable.so $(LIBFILES)


wordcount: wordcount.o io.o libhtable.a
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o wordcount -static io.o wordcount.o libhtable.a


wordcount-dynamic: wordcount.o io.o libhtable.so
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o wordcount-dynamic io.o  wordcount.o libhtable.so

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS) libhtable.so libhtable.a
```

Comment: Problem is not makefie but C-file: you are referencing a symbol (function) `htab_init` that cannot be found.

Comment: Does your file htab_init.c really have a function named htab_init?

Comment: Fyi, you may well run into problems using the *same* .o files for both your dynamic lib and your static lib. One (the latter) is just a package of object code files, and is no different than stacking those object files on the link line. But a shared lib is different. The exported symbols within the object code must be properly attributed and/or marked for export (either globally or per id). Suggest you curtail this down. And unrelated, but important, maybe debug this build system and see if you can pick out why `wordcount.o` appears *twice* in your link line. That shouldn't be the case.